# what is size of facebook app's fluid canvas

Tags: facebook, canvas

hi i want to develop an Facebook app anybody knows what is the exact size of Facebook fluid canvas in pixel according to its width and height.and can we make a full screen app.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go for size 1300 * 768. This is the correct height of the facebook app's fluid canvas.